# Checking (value or type) against errors returned by fmt.Errorf

Tags: go

If a piece of code has its own error type as in

```
var ErrSomethingWentWrong = errors.New("Something went wrong"
```

I believe in my code I can do this

```golang
import github.com/therepo/theproject/thepackage/thatexportstheaboveerror

// code that might return the above error
if err == thatexportstheaboveerror.ErrSomethingWentWrong {
    // handle the particular case
}
```

What happens when the error returned is via `fmt.Errorf` as in [this](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/client_auth.go#L75) case?

```golang
return fmt.Errorf("ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods %v, no supported methods remain", keys(tried))
```

How can value (or type or whatever) check/assertion should be performed go-idiomatically?
Is this the only way around it?

```
if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "unable to authenticate") {
       // handle the particular error
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors . `fmt.Errorf` could include another "static" error that you can check against with the methods described in the post.

Comment: yes but in the specific example I am citing, no error is wrapped.

Comment: The type of sentinel error you're using was once common practice, but now as of Go 1.13, they should generally be avoided. Of course, your question is still very valid, since not all code _can_ be changed. Just be aware of this for new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Go version 1.13, [the `errors` package](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) has included the concept of "wrapping" errors.  A routine returning a "wrapped" error calls `fmt.Errorf` using the `%w` verb in the format, to wrap an inner error into an outer error.  An outer error can then be tested to see if it contains a particular inner error.

Prior to that, [`xerrors`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/xerrors) provided the same general concept.

Both of these require that whoever *produces* the error value use the provided wrapping interface.  The routine you are asking about—part of https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh—does not do this.  Some older code that doesn't wrap errors provides certain kind of error-testing functions.  For instance, when [`os.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) returns an error, [`os.IsNotExist`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist) will tell you if that error is because the file does not exist.

Unfortunately this particular package has no such test, so you're pretty much stuck with what you've suggested (direct string inspection) if you really want to know, programmatically, that this error came from this particular source.

Answer (score 0):

While the `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` package does not surface sentinel errors (wrapped or otherwise), the `ssh.Dial` function provides a suggestion to use `ssh.NewClientConn` for more control. I did some light research and it looks this may be the workaround:

1. Use `net.Dial` to obtain `net.Conn`

   - see https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dial
2. Use `ssh.NewClientConn` to obtain `ssh.Conn` and control channels

   - see https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#NewClientConn
3. Use `ssh.NewClient` to obtain `ssh.Client`

   - see https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#NewClient

This allows you to break up the convenience function into three separate steps so that you can better identify which of those three points are the source of a failure and surface a custom wrapped error so that your business logic can handle those specific scenarios (e.g., "failed port connection attempt" vs "failed authentication").